# LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MyClass.cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am receiving the previous error with compiling a project in my solution. `MyClass` is within the project I am trying to compile (with included in project set to true), so I am unsure as to how it is an "external symbol". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Update: I think that this is definitely a Microsoft issue as if I change my configuration type from .exe to .dll it works properly

Comment: The first thing I would fix is giving your class a descriptive name. `MyClass` doesn't count.

Comment: Next, check that you have included your class's header file in the source file that fails to compile. You should see something like `#include "MyClass.h"` at the top.

Comment: @Cody Gray: The class does have a descriptive name, but I've been told to not give out too much information on the projects I'm working on over the Internet. I have included the header file.

Comment: @Casebash: Fair enough. It's difficult to tell what else might be wrong without seeing the code that is generating a linker error. In this case, "external" refers to outside of the current translation unit, not external to the project.

Comment: Besides "MyClass" really being "SuperDuperTradeSecret", it seems unlikely the title is the exact error message you get.

Comment: @Thomas: That is what confuses me. There are plenty of other unresolved symbol errors on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find any where the symbol was an underscore in front of a class name as above

Comment: The C++ language does not allow to have a '.' inside a symbol name. So it's unlikely that this is the actual error message. How does the '.cpp' gets in the error?

Comment: @harper: Well it is Microsoft, so they sometimes depart from the standards

Comment: I can't recall ever having seen a ".cpp" in a LNK2001 error:  The `_` in front of `MyClass` seems to indicate that `MyClass` is actually a function (a `_` prefix is used to decorate cdecl functions), but without seeing the exact error message, it's really impossible to say.

Comment: @Casebash: Well, if you think Microsoft does not provide a sufficient tool, use another. But the '.' separates a member from the object. This can't go through the compiler as one symbol. As you answered you added this symbol by an errorneous entry in the "entry point" field. Reasonable, since it's not an output from the compiler.

Comment: @harper: The linker doesn't work with C++ and has its own rules for symbols.

Comment: @Thomas Edleson: I just said that the C++ compiler can't be blaimed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the entry point to MyClass.cpp when I should have left it blank

Comment: You should be able to accept your own answer by clicking the hollow checkmark to the left. That way, others know that your problem has been solved.

Comment: @Cody: Yeh, the system was forcing me to wait 2 days

Comment: No worries. I just saw that 2 days had already passed, and I thought that I would remind you.